# How to change data-table Column names value with first row of same data-table

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, webforms

I am getting data table(dt1) values  from other data table(dt) like below

```
DataTable dt1 = dt;
```

i am getting output like below in dt1

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nteug.jpg

I want output like below

```
ChildrenBoth  CCTVcameras   AvailableOpenSpace    SufficientSpace

ChildrenBoth  CCTVcameras   AvailableOpenSpace    SufficientSpace
     No             No             No                  No
```

I don't want Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5 as header and header should be first row of datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this on multiple levels. Like in the GridView with `HeaderText`

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="MyHeader 1" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MyHeader 2">
            <ItemTemplate>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Or change the name in the DataTable.

```
dt1.Columns[0].ColumnName = "MyHeader";
```

Or in the query itself.

```
SELECT column4 as 'new column name' FROM table
```

Give the colums the names of the first row

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    dt.Columns[i].ColumnName = dt.Rows[0][i].ToString();
}
```

Comment: 1) i dont want to go with gridview, i want into data-table only 2) i dont want to pass static like your second answer. 3) i am not getting data directly from select query, i did some convert column to rows with datatable. I need result in datatable only. your answer is not helpful to me. @VDWWD

Comment: I've updated my answer. I did not see the part of giving the columns the same name as the first row values.